# A Coroutine is returning a coroutine after await

Tags: python, django, async-await, fastapi

I'm writing tests for a fastAPI on django with an ASGI server (adapted this [tutorial](https://www.stavros.io/posts/fastapi-with-django/)). My fastAPI side of the test keeps returning errors and I'm trying in vain to fix it.

My need is about creating a user to test the API.

```
@sync_to_async
def _create_user(self, username, email):
    try:
        return User.objects.create(username=username, email=email)
    except:
        return None

async def setUp(self):
    task = asyncio.create_task(self._create_user(username="user", email="email@email.com"))
    self.user = await task
```

Running this test, it turn out that `self.user` is a coroutine and it's impossible to access the attributes I expect.

How to solve this ?

**Update** :

Removed async for `_create_user(self, username, email)`.

Comment: Why do you wrap an ``async`` function with ``sync_to_async``? Why is ``_create_user`` ``async`` in the first place, seeing how it does nothing asynchronous, aside from erroneously trying to ``await print(..)``? Finally, why is ``setUp`` ``async``? This does not seem like it needs any async at all. You are inherently wrapping a synchronous action ``User.objects.create`` into several empty layers of ``async`` only to (incorrectly) unwrap the empty layers to then run the synchronous code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There are things I don't master a lot. Wrapping asyn with sync_to_async was for debugging purpose, and I didn't remove it before posting my question. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/#asgiref.sync.sync_to_async
decorator sync_to_async should decorates sync functions. (see example)

Comment: Sounds good. But I get this warning `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SyncToAsync.__call__' was never awaited
  self.setUp()`

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer,.......................

Simply Create a normal synchronize function and call with with sync_to_async() function

This function is used to get the user_object

```
def get_user_object(mobile_no):
    user_object = CustomUser.objects.get(mobile_no=mobile_no)
    return user_object
```

This method is running in async so we need to call a sync function to async to get rid of error......

```
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
async def connect(self):
    username = await database_sync_to_async(get_user_object)(mobile_no="+9999999999")
    print(user_object)
```